# Any way to compress comluns into an unique shorter value to do data row comparisons

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, hash, hashmap

i'm thinking of do make database update a little easier.

For the case:
Need to compare all columns from DB A to DB B by PK, to know if this row needs to be updated.

Easy way is to connect all columns with separators then do comparison. 
EG:

```
string row_A=column1+column2+.....column20;
string row_B=column1+column2+.....column20;
if(row_A!=row_B)
{...}
```

But I'm wondering is there a better way like compute these columns into a unique value,
something like hash or  something else, then i can save these values in to table.

```
uniqueValue_A=makeUniqueValue(column1+column2+.....column20);
uniqueValue_B=makeUniqueValue(column1+column2+.....column20);
if(uniqueValue_A!=uniqueValue_B)
{...}
```

Then i just need to compare these unique numbers or strings.

Comment: You could use checksum for something like this. Would make it a bit less typing.

Comment: Hashing is not reliable. Think about concatenation: `J` + `ames` is the same as `Jam` + `es`. Hashing can have the same kind of collision. If you're having a performance problem, consider improving indexing to support the comparison. If you're not having a performance problem, optimize when you need to.

Comment: understand, the data is too huge, can't make all columns indexed. just asking better ideas

Answer (score 0):

If you had timestamps of when these rows where last updated, or a row version number, usually one of those is implemented on tables which need to be 'synced', and updated/incremented each time an update happens.

Otherwise if not, a hash function (hash of all cols separately) then a hash of that,  would be your second best, if comparing each value is not viable.

P.S. Hashing will never guarantee that there is no collision, but depending on how big your dataset is, it is unlikely.

Comment: yes, sir. we have time inserted and updated, and ... something else..even that still need full comparisons ...

Comment: can you not check against the Updated/Inserted time? If they don't match, means that the later one got changed. That is, if both times in both databases are the same unless changed.

Comment: that what we do usually, but sometime that mechanism no work perfectly.